# using localhost for security

Tags: php, security

Is it a good idea to use localhost/127.0.0.1/::1 for security to allow a script to access content within the site, whilst presenting username/password login for anything else?

For example,

```
if(in_array($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"], array("127.0.0.1","::1"))){
  // allow internal access
  // (ie. scripts on the same site can access this protected data)
} else if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
  // check if username and password are correct
  // - if yes - allow external access (ie. perhaps from an app or 3rd party site)
  // - if not - deny access
} else {
  // deny access
}
```

I know I could probably use a token system to check if the request was internally made, but if I were to distribute the script, surely someone could look at the script and make a token to 'break in'.

I guess if a token system is therefore required, it would be best to generate an encryption key for each user that wants to use the script. Would an encryption key be safe to store within a PHP file or better to store in a database? What is the best way to store it?

Comment: If you're planning on hosting your project in a shared hosting environment, I don't think that verifying against localhost is a good idea.

Comment: this is true... any suggestions on check that the request origin came from the actual site are welcome - I didn't want to check the server IP as I know these things could possibly be spoofed, though I thought that perhaps localhost would look at the end user's own machine instead (so perhaps not spoofable?)

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR"]` will allways be the localhost address if you access the app through localhost. If not - SERVER_ADDR will be the server's address and REMOTE_ADDR will be the client's address. But why would you need this anyway? I mean ... if I get it right, you want your website to crawl through itself?!

Comment: hmm.. I see that they are going to be different when live.... this is going to be a security layer to provide access to JSON data from MySQL database - so only the site can access it and users with authorisation ... doing it like this to try and simplify the bakend of the site so that the data isn't requested in 2 places/2 different ways, but just one (whilst checking if the requester is allowed to access it)

Comment: That makes no sense - your website can read straight from the MySQL database. I assume you want JSON encoded data for ajax requests, but that's a client-side technology - you can only check the user's credentials, it can never appear to be coming from your server.

Comment: if login, JSON is for 3rd party sites/apps - if no login, JSON is for powering the site ... I know the site can read straight from the database, but if I wanted to change something or add an extra feature - it means I need to add it twice, ie. would need to maintain 2 scripts to do the same thing. basically this would be like an API - request is made internally or externally, and data is sent from the API via JSON - which is then processed either by the site itself, or by the app/3rd party

Comment: An API should be an external interface to your application's internal features. Using it for internal processing is pointless at the least. You will always have the methods and/or functions that do the work - that's not an additional script. Your API must only validate outside requests and pass the input/output back and forth between those internal methods and the outside world.

Comment: In other words ... you should design them as different layers rather than different scripts.

Comment: In that case, it is probably wise to perhaps get some classes together - where both the API and internal functions can call the same class to generate the same data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3239/discussion-between-mrj-and-narf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's *relatively* safe to do, as long as you have full access control over your server (No shared hosting whatsoever).

Your code has a few flaws though, you'll want to check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to be localhost/127.0.0.1/::1. Not `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`.

Then on the second if statement you'll have to check for `isset($_POST['user'])` and `isset($_POST['pass'])` before using `empty()` on a possibly unexistent index.